# How to share auth0 authentication information between 2 different APIs?

Tags: javascript, express, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, auth0

Pretty much new on APIs and microservice world.

**i am using auth0 for authentication.**

I have a **convert** express API POST endpoint which will only work if the user is authenticated, however for frontend -> ( home page, login button, login from auth0 callback, redirection) I using different api **Homepage** express api.

After user logs in from homepage api, from his profile dashboard user tries to send a post request to convert API endpoint this doesn't work and throws an error `check.state argument is missing`.

**How do I make sure if one API authenticates that authentication information should be shared with another API  endpoint which needs authentication?**

```
app.use(‘/authUrls’,requiresAuth(),authUrlsRouter)   //convert api post request
```

Comment: Use middleware instead.

Comment: can you please elaborate how middleware can solve my problem, see i cant change my authentication strategy ( auth0) API 1 authenticates -> post -> API 2 endooint( which needs authentication) this is my system as of now

Answer (score 0):

This may be an assumption, but it appears that you are creating a regular web application with Node.js, and what you want is authentication per session, not per API endpoint. This [quickstart](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nodejs) from Auth0 walks through it nicely. It uses [Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org) and express-session to provide middleware.

As per the [tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nodejs#storing-and-retrieving-user-data-from-the-session):

> In a typical web application, the credentials used to authenticate a user are only transmitted during the login request. If authentication succeeds, a session is established and maintained via a cookie set in the user's browser. Each subsequent request does not contain credentials, but rather the unique cookie that identifies the session.

*How it works:* when the **login** api is called and completed successfully, the user's authentication is stored in that session. Whenever other API's are called that require an authenticated user, you can just include the [middleware](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nodejs#middleware-to-protect-routes) (in the quickstart it is called 'secured'): it will query that respective session's data and allow / disallow based on the user's authentication status.

For example, the *convert* endpoint:
`router.post('/convert', secured(), this.convertfunction);`

And a non-auth endpoint:
`router.get('/other', this.otherfunction);`

The full tutorial has much more information available. But this illustrates how middleware will solve your problem.